# Swift and Codable: Encodable tree struct terminating in values that obey custom protocol

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable

I am attempting to make a tree data structure obey the encodable protocol. The tree terminates in "some object" that obeys the protocol "Terminal". Terminal extends Codable.

Each node of the tree is a pair. It has a key, and a value. The value is either a pair, or a Terminal.

There are two main issues:

1)
I would like this structure to encode to JSON such that

```swift
class Pair: Codable {
   var key: String?
   var value: Codable?
}

let outputSimple = Pair(key: "a test key", value: "a test value")
// encodes to
// {"a test key": "a test value"}
// whereas currently encodes to
// {}

let outputComplex = Pair(key: "a parent", value: Pair(key: "another pair", value: "a test value"))
// encodes to
// {"a parent": {"another pair", "a test value"}}
```

EDIT: part 2 might be confusing the issue slightly. To clarify issue above, if I had

```swift
class Pair: Codable {
   var key: String
   var value: String
}
let p = Pair(key:"foo", value: "bar")
```

how could I get it to output {"foo":"bar"} rather than {key:foo, value:bar}? I tried

```swift
    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        container.encode(contentsOf: [key: value])
    }
```

but get the error "Instance method 'encode(contentsOf:)' requires that '(key: _, value: _)' conform to 'Encodable'"

2) I was attempting the following but it doesn't appear to work. I get "Pair does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"

```swift
protocol TreeNode: Codable {} 
struct Pair: TreeNode {
   var key: String?
   var value: TreeNode?
}

extension String: TreeNode {}
```

This one I can get around by making TreeNode a class with Pair a subclass. It's also likely this is correct Swift behaviour. However, I wondered if more pairs of eyes could explain the issue. I assumed that as long as I ensured all values are either of type pair, or something else that obeys Codable then it would work.

Comment: Have a look at [GenericJSON](https://github.com/zoul/generic-json-swift/blob/master/GenericJSON/JSON.swift) for creating a dynamic, type-safe JSON using `Codable`. You could simplify that to fit your need for a `Tree`/`Pair`.

Comment: Thanks. That's the approach I'm taking but it involves wrapping the terminal nodes in a class. The encode method for that class then does the GenericJSON style encoding

Answer (score 3):

This cannot work.

`value` must be a concrete type which conforms to `Codable`, not the protocol itself or a second protocol conforming to `Codable`

What you can do is to declare `value` as generic

```
class Pair<T: Codable>: Codable {
    var key: String?
    var value: T?

    init(key: String?, value: T?) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

It can encode both `outputSimple` and `outputComplex`

Comment: I assume that's an answer to part 2? 
Part 1 would still encoded to {"key": "foo", "value": "bar"} for  Pair(key: "foo", value: "bar"}?

Comment: Actually both parts have the same issue: You cannot use `Codable` or another *protocol* conforming to `Codable` as type. I would use `nil` as terminator.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is another data structure "Array" left out of my discussion above for simplicity. Array can have Any codable object so I can't specify T in Array<T> other than Array<Any> and Any isn't codable/

Comment: I may have confused things by making this a two part question. 
In part 1, now assuming key and value are both strings, I need to make a dictionary of "{<key value>: <value value>}" rather than the standard codable {"key": <key value>, "value": <value value>}

Comment: `T` can be also an array for example `[Pair]` but all items must have the same `value` type. You cannot encode `Any` at all.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the requirement to have an Array of different encodable types means that the generic approach will not work. I can get around some of this by wrapping the terminal types in a class and having nodes and terminals share a common Encodable parent. However, part 1 is still an issue